# retrieving the max value of all the selects in a page with Xpath

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I want to retrieve max value for each combobox present in a web page, with **xpath**.

Here is a sample HTML containing several combobox with choices:

```
<label> <span class="invisible_spoken">Some choice</span>
<select class="select_class">
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1" >
1
</option>
<option value="2" >
2
</option>
</select>
</label>
<label> <span class="invisible_spoken">Some choice</span>
<select class="select_class">
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
</label>
<label> <span class="invisible_spoken">Some choice</span>
<select class="select_class">
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
</select>
</label
```

**What I would want to retrieve is the maximum value of each combobox**, sample output :

```
2, 3, 1
```

I've tried with an expression like :

```
//table[@id="rooms"]//select[contains(@class, "b_selectbox")]/option[not(//table[@id="rooms"]//select[contains(@class, "b_selectbox")]/option/@value > @value)]/@value
```

But it is returning just combobox max values of the maximum combo value, in the sample case just 3 that is the highest, in the case there will be two combobox with maximum values equals to 3, then it will return those 2 ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xpath Selector for Options with highest value.

```
//label/select[@class="select_class123"]/option[not(../option/@value > @value)]
o/p: Option elements with highest values.

(//label/select[@class="select_class"]/option[not(../option/@value > @value)])/@value
o/p: 2, 3, 1
```

Test XML [`XPath online`](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi):

```
<select class="select_class">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<select class="select_class">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<select class="select_class">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
</select>
```